# Windows 8.1 can't see Windows 10 network share

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 Home box which I'm sharing some files from.  From a Windows 8.1 box, I can sometimes connect to it and sometimes not.  Usually, if I cannot connect, by connecting the other way (10 to 8.1 which seems to work) I can then connect the way I want to (8.1 to 10).

Anyone have any ideas what is going on here?

A

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any error messages? Is it available to ping the machine when it is not available to access the share? Have you tried to access the share both with the IP address and the FQDN?

Please try the following command line to reset the tcp/ip stack to have a trpubleshoot.
ipconfig /flushdns (Clear the dns cache)
nbtstat -RR (release and refesh NetBIOS names)
netsh int ip reset (reset ip settings)
netsh winsock reset (Reset Winsock Catalog)
Reboot